# Why can't I edit "Settings" on rules components in the Rules UI?

Tags: 7, rules

When I click to edit a rule in the Rules UI, "Settings" is displayed in blue and upon clicking "Settings" the "Name", "Tags", "Active" and "Weight" options are presented.

However, when I click to edit a rules component, "Settings" is displayed in black and I cannot edit the name of the rule nor the arguments.

Before, I solved this problem by:

- clearing the Drupal cache (twice)
- clearing the cache in my browser and restarting it
- switching to a different browser (e.g., from Firefox to Safari)

However, this time none of the above worked.  How can I edit the settings for rules components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem when using entity-rc1.  Upgrading to entity 1.0 resolved the issue for me.